# Quick and easy way to convert lua table to xml

Tags: xml, lua

Is there a quick and easy way to convert lua table to xml? A friend has been doing it for me but it takes too long, and I cant find anything helpful on the web that works. Thanks

Comment: There are probably many ways. See one here: https://github.com/britzl/luatoxml.

Comment: Please give an example of the conversion you have in mind.

Comment: I would like a civ 5 mod converted from lua to xml, here is a download link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4numaaduwt0ll0z/HNR%20%28v%2010%29.rar?dl=0